# Rails checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string column in my database which is either "artist" or "listener", and I want the user to be able to choose which string the column is populated with by clicking the appropriate checkbox. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use radio button here:

```
# Imagine it is User model and user_type field
<%= form_for User.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :user_type, "artist" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :user_type, "listener" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I disn't know where it is. So you can use any model

Comment: and I don't recommend you to use word `type` in your database :)

Answer (score 1):

`f.check_box :my_field, {}, "artist", "listener"`

This would make `my_field` be "artist" when it's checked, and "listener" when unchecked.

Comment: would this make just one checkbox?

Comment: Yes, if you want to see both options, you should be using radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: you can use checkboxes, so user will be allowed to check both  of them. Sometimes it is useful

Answer (score 1):

You should use radio-buttons for that matter. Also make sure to put that logic into the model (validations).

```
# model
class User
  TYPES = %w(artist listener)

  validates_inclusion_of :user_type, :in => TYPES
end

# view
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <% User::TYPES.each do |type| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :user_type, type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: little more nicer `validates :user_type, :inclusion => {:in => TYPES }` :)